# on_epoch_end() not called in keras fit_generator()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, training-data

I followed [this tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to generate data on-the-fly with the `fit_generator()` Keras method, to train my Neural Network model.

I created a generator by using the `keras.utils.Sequence` class .The call to `fit_generator()` is:

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator=EVDSSequence(images_train, TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_IMG_DIR, INPUT_JSON_DIR, SPLIT_CHAR, sizeArray, NCHW, shuffle=True),
                              steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=EPOCHS,
                              validation_data=EVDSSequence(images_valid, VALID_BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_IMG_DIR, INPUT_JSON_DIR, SPLIT_CHAR, sizeArray, NCHW, shuffle=True),
                              validation_steps=None,
                              callbacks=callbacksList, verbose=1,
                              workers=0, max_queue_size=1, use_multiprocessing=False)
```

`steps_per_epoch` is `None`, so the number of steps per epoch is calculated by the Keras `__len()__` method.

As said in the link above:

> Here, the method `on_epoch_end` is triggered once at the very beginning as well as at the end of each epoch. If the `shuffle` parameter is set to `True`, we will get a new order of exploration at each pass (or just keep a linear exploration scheme otherwise).

My problem is that `on_epoch_end()` method is called only at the very beginning, but never at the end of each epoch.
So, at each epoch, the batch order is always the same.

I tried to use `np.ceil` instead of `np.floor` in `__len__()` method, but with no success.

Do you know why `on_epoch_end` is not called at the end of each epoch? Could you tell me any work-around to shuffle the order of my batches at the end (or at the beginning) of each epoch?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem. I have no idea why this happened, but there's a way to walkaround: call `on_epoch_end()` within `__len__()`, since `__len__()` will be called every epoch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Anyway, I already (temporary) solved, days ago, right this way, but this shuffles all samples.
My original aim was to shuffle only the order with whom batches are supplied to the net, preserving the order of samples inside a single batch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've encountered the same problem and I did not realize it until I found the results of my experiments were quite weird.

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to the issue:  [`Keras model.fit not calling Sequence.on_epoch_end() #35911`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35911)

A quick fix would be to use a [LambdaCallback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LambdaCallback) (note that I use `fit` which should be sufficient, as `fit_generator` is deprecated)

```py
from tf.keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

model.fit(generator, callbacks=[LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=generator.on_epoch_end)])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

And I'm finding that when you make an on_predict_end() callback_lambda, it is not called at predict end.  Btw, predict() takes a callbacks=list(...) argument.

Also, it appears you can test a callback like this:

```
(create your 'model' object)
callback_batch_end <- callback_lambda(
    on_batch_end = function(batch, logs) {
        cat("Hello world\n")
    }
)
callback_batch_end$on_batch_end(1, "x")
(prints 'Hello world')
callback_predict_end <- callback_lambda(
    on_predict_end = function(logs) {
        cat("Hello world\n")
    }
)
callback_predict_end$on_predict_end("x")
(prints nothing)
```